# scale html properly and appending new information with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm really rough with javascript/jquery and am having trouble thinking about this code.
I did what I want using PHP but it causes the html to mess up when a certain amount of new entries is added.

The code I have in PHP:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($educationArray[0]); $i++)
    {   
        echo "<div style=\"float:left; margin-right:50px; margin-bottom:30px; \">";
        echo "<label>Institution Name</label>";
        echo "<span>".$newarray[$i]['Institution']."</span>";
        echo "<label>Location</label>";
        echo "<span>".$newarray[$i]['Location']."</span>";
        echo "<label>Start Date</label>";
        echo "<span>".$newarray[$i]['StartDate']."</span>";
        echo "<label>End Date</label>";
        echo "<span>".$newarray[$i]['EndDate']."</span>";
        echo "<label>Degree</label>";
        echo "<span>".$newarray[$i]['Degree']."</span>";
        echo "<label>Date Received Degree</label>";
        echo "<span>".$newarray[$i]['DegreeDate']."</span>";
        echo "<label>GPA</label>";
        echo "<span>".$newarray[$i]['GPA']."</span>";

        echo "</div>";

    }

    ?>
```

I want to be able to have this done automatically in javascript.
The code i have to add new information to the database is:

```
    <h3 style="float:left;">Add Education</h3>
 <button style="float:left;" class="editInfoButtons" id="AddEducationButton"></button>
 <div style="float:left;" id="EducationInfo" class="modal-basicInfo">
           <div style="height:600px;width:260px;">
                <a title="Close" class="close">x</a>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?user=" . $userInfo['Id']; ?>" >


    <label for="InstitutionName">Institution Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="schoolName" id="InstitutionName" />



    <label for="InstitutionLocation">Location: </label>
    <input type="text" name="schoolLocation" id="InstitutionLocation" />

  <br /><br />

    <label for="DatesAttended">Dates of Attendance</label>
    <input type="date" id="DateBegin" name="dateBegin"  />-<input type="date" name="dateEnd" id="DateEnd" />

    <br /><br />

    <label for="DegreeEarned">Degree Earned</label>
    <input id="DegreeEarned" name="DegreeEarned" type="text" />

    <label for="DateEarned">Date Earned: </label>
    <input style="float:left;" name="DateEarned" id="DateEarned" type="date" />

        <br />
        <br />

    <label for="GPA">GPA: </label>
    <input id="GPA" name="GPA" type="text" />



 <input type="submit" id="AddSchools" name="AddSchools" class="button" value="Add Institute" />
</form>
</div>
```

Quick description of what is going on: When they hit the button a div appears where they can add the information. Once they input the information and hit submit, it gets saved to the database, the div disappears and the page is reloaded to display the new information that was added pushing the old information down.

Any guidance on doing this using Javascript/Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jQuery you can use ajax request then make a success call back function and prepend(to put the newly inserted information at the top, pushes the old information down) in your div.

let me give you a head start in ajax...

```
$("#AddSchools").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert-to-db.php",
        data: { schoolName:$("#InstitutionName").val(),
                schoolLocation:$("#InstitutionLocation").val(),
                DateBegin:$("#DateBegin").val(),
                DegreeEarned:$("#DegreeEarned").val(),
                DateEarned:$("#DateEarned").val(),
                GPA:$("#GPA").val()
                } ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
         $("div").prepend("<label>Institution Name</label><br>"+$("#InstitutionName").val()+"(and so on...)");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This helped me so much! I would up vote if I could. Thank you!!